# accessing variables using loop counter in java, android

Tags: java, android, loops, counter

how can I access declared variables using counter, in a loop, like this:

declared variables:

```
Button square0, square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6,
        square7, square8, temp;
```

accessing them with a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    (Button) ("square"+i).setBackgroundResource();
```

Comment: This is really bad practice in any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't without resorting to some really dubious magic (I don't even think you can do this with reflection in Java).

Use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy...

```
Button[] btnArray = new Button[10]; 
 //assign all squares to the array 
btnArray[0] = square1;
for(Button btn : btnArray){
btn.setBackGroundResource();
}
```

or even better use a List like

```
List<Button> myBtnList = new ArrayList<Button>();
myBtnList.add(square1);
```

add till all buttons are added then use the for each loop as illustrated above.

Comment: btnArray.add(square); won't work with an array. Use btnArray[0] = square;

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned this is bad practice in any programming language. If you want to access a list of things (in your case `Buttons`), you should use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or an [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Here is an example using an `ArrayList` of `Buttons`:

```
List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

Button button1 = new Button();
Button button3 = new Button();
Button button2 = new Button();

buttonList.add(button1);
buttonList.add(button2);
buttonList.add(button3);

// How to get a button out
for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++)
    myButton = buttonList.get(i);
    // Do something with myButton here.
}
```